# Magento2 : No Updation in custom table for module

Tags: magento-2.1, setup-upgrade

I am using upgradeschema to update field in my custom table 
i want to add gender and city in this table but after running upgrade command on CLI no updation in database table 
here's my upgradeschema

```
<?php
namespace Contact\Modules\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
class UpgradeSchema implements  UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
                            ModuleContextInterface $context){
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0) {

            // Get module table
            $tableName = $setup->getTable('modules_contact');

            // Check if the table already exists
            if ($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) == true) {
                // Declare data
                $columns = [
                    'gender' => [
                        'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'comment' => 'gender',
                    ],
                     'city' => [
                        'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'comment' => 'city',
                    ],
                ];

                $connection = $setup->getConnection();
                foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
                    $connection->addColumn($tableName, $name, $definition);
                }

            }
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: plz show your module.xml file

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Contact_Modules" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under app/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Contact_Modules" setup_version="1.0.2" />    

</config>
```

Under UpgradeSchema.php file,

```
<?php
namespace Contact\Modules\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;


class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2', '<')) {
            $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('modules_contact'),
                'gender',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 20,
                    'nullable' => false,
                     'comment' => 'gender'
                ]
            );

            $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('modules_contact'),
                'city',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,                    
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'comment' => 'City'
                ]
            );
        }

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade command**

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy